# Dynamic Programming for TSP with constraints

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, traveling-salesman

I am trying to solve the following problem:

There are several cities in the map. We know the distance between each city. We would like to build a road to connect these cities. However, the maximum distance of the road is x. So, what algorithm should I use to find the road that connects as many cities as possible under the constraints?

Thanks!

Comment: Can the road have branches?

Comment: Thanks, the road does not have branches. Does this mean I need to solve the problem with BFS?

Comment: Can the road return to a city that it already passed?

Comment: This is as hard as the standard TSP, so more information about your input constraints is probably necessary.